# Android tablet as second screen via USB

Tags: usb-power, screen, touchscreen, android

***Also can you charge tablet/phone using the USB ports?*** is solved

as the title

Comment: I removed most of what you wrote initially since it seemed to be a justification for the premise that USB can be "used for data".  Of course it can, no one is going to argue that it cannot.

Comment: i saw like 5 posts on stackoverflow where they said usb was used for power **ONLY**

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks! Right now it's two questions and the only answer that exists addresses only the powering issue.

Comment: WRT using the screen, you might want to ask yourself the same question about your PC, since the pi is really a small general purpose computer with a normal USB.  Can you use that android tablet as a second screen on your laptop, etc?  If so, then there may be a way to do it with the pi.  If not, then there is your answer.  I think you already know which way this is ;\

Comment: with the  pc its diffrent if found alot of software for windows but not raspi not even linux

Answer (score 1):

USB ports do transmit power, I was able to power my Pi from a laptop and a USB-MicroUSB adapter. That means that technically you *could* charge a phone/tablet with a Pi, but the power output is very low and the consumption might be more than the input. You should use a [powered USB hub](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/powered-usb-hub).

Comment: The +/2 models should be good for 1.2 A, which might be enough for some phones but probably not tablets.